# What does this boot/restore-time message mean (before Windows launch)?

Tags: windows-7, boot, sleep

I recently moved to a new laptop, and because the hardware was the same (HP ZBook 15) I decided to see if I could save a lot of time by just moving the hard drive over.  This seemed to work (aside from one issue with the BitLocker encryption, now fixed), *but* whenever I either boot or return from (long) sleep I see the following message before Windows (7 Enterprise) starts/restores:

[image: photo of message]

What does this message mean, and should I be concerned?

I don't see this message when unlocking after an hour or so but I do see it after it's sat overnight -- at times when Windows displays a "restoring" message before starting back up.  I also see it on boot.  In both cases, the message is there for about 30 seconds and then Windows proceeds.  I haven't investigated that "Configuration Utility" option (never heard of it).

System information (I don't know what of this is relevant): Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, 32GB, i7-4800MQ CPU @ 2.70GHz (x 8).

Comment: you should not be worried. the screen just shows you the status of disks being populated by the Intel Chipsets RST controllers. you could use RST to set up RAID volumes, or implement other hardware-based storage features that must be in place before boot.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas -- never saw this on the old machine, so does that mean there's some hardware difference between the two after all?

Comment: well, some motherboards have multiple IO chips (one of mine has 2 ports for Intel chipset, two ports on a JMicron chip, and two on a Marvell raid controller) so by connecting a drive to a SATA port associated with Intel RST, the feature comes on. It may delay longer, since you now have two devices on the chip and might want to create a RAID0/1 configuratiuon. Your old system may not have implemented an Intel IO chip at all (for instance an AMD motherboard), or had disabled this prompt in the BIOS.